# Best practice when changing PHP Data to JS Data via AJAX (especially arrays)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

**(Secondary title): ajax array recieved as json encoded PHP array not behaving as javascript array**

For some reason, my PHP array gets sent over to JavaScript just fine, but when I try to access an individual key of the array, it doesn't return anything, or it returns some other value which doesn't correspond. I am of course using `json_encode()` in the corresponding PHP file (**echoClientData.php**):

```
$id = $_GET['selected_id'];
    $id = str_replace("clientSel","",$id);
    $getclientinfo = "SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE `ClientID` = $id";

    if ($result = $Database->query($getclientinfo))
    {
        $row = $result->fetch_row();
        $output = $row;
    }
echo json_encode($output);
```

This code works fine:

```
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "echoClientData.php?selected_id=" + HTMLid,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    test = data;
                    $('#client-detail-box').html(test);
                }
            });
```

And returns an array into the `#client-detail-box` div, e.g.

```
["1566","","Adrian","Tiggert","","","","","","","","","","","","0000-00-00","0000-00-00","0.00","","0","","","102","Dimitri Papazov","2006-02-24","102","Dimitri Papazov","2006-02-24","1","0","0"]
```

However, when I do

```
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "echoClientData.php?selected_id=" + HTMLid,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    test = data[3]; // should be "Tiggert"
                    $('#client-detail-box').html(test);
                }
            });
        }
```

It returns

```
5
```

Comment: I would be especially impressed if someone knows why it actually outputted `5`..I know it has to do with the encoding...and I suppose that may be explanation enough...

Comment: I believe the returned data was processed as a string.  Since `5` was the 4th character, (or array key `3`) this is what was returned.  If you used `data[12]`, it would have returned `A`.

Comment: Ah man...exactly! Bonus points!...If I could... :3

Comment: This is a well-presented, Grade A question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to do one of two things when returning JSON from PHP.

Either set your content type in PHP before echoing your output so that jQuery automatically parses it to a javascript object or array:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

or specify that jQuery should treat the returned data as json:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "echoClientData.php?selected_id=" + HTMLid,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
        var test = data[3]; // should be "Tiggert"
        $('#client-detail-box').html(test);
    }
});
```

Be aware, that in your current PHP script, in the event that your query fails, you will be `json_encode`ing an undefined variable.

Also, your PHP code is entirely open to SQL injection.  Make sure you sanitize your `$id`, either by casting it to `(int)` or by escaping it before sending it through in your query.

Comment: This is golden. Very much appreciated. In the past, I've gotten away without `dataType: 'json'`, and my educated guess is that it's because I was dealing with a simple string before, as opposed to an array which needs re-encoding/parsing

Comment: Also note that using `dataType: 'json'` worked even **without** the php header (although I'm adding the header too to be safe)

Comment: Yes, you only need to do one or the other in order for this to work.  When jQuery processes the ajax call and finds the `application/json` header, it parses the returned data automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using JSON.parse on the value you are getting back from PHP?

e.g.

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url: "echoClientData.php?selected_id=" + HTMLid,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data)
            {
                test = JSON.parse(data); // should be "Tiggert"
                $('#client-detail-box').html(test[3]);
            }
        });
```

That seems like it would be a fix.

Comment: Using the code you posted verbatum still returned `5` instead of `Tiggert` :\

Comment: Yah I was just taking a look at that... Interesting for sure... is there any downside to just setting var test = data and doing test[3]?

Comment: I edited the code slightly. See if that works for ya?

Comment: I would, in this case, go with SuperJar's solution. Didn't notice you didn't have a content type which will probably make a huge difference.

Comment: `test = JSON.parse(data); $('#client-detail-box').html(test[3]);` worked!

Comment: Nice glad to hear it! I would still say that putting the dataType in there will be beneficial and best practice. Anywho, good luck to you!